Constructing a $1$-form that vanishes iff the connection is compatible with the $G$-structure
I'm studying $G$-structures from Crainic's lecture notes. I'm stuck on the proof of Proposition $4.18$ at page $122$.
Let $\mathscr{N}(\mathfrak{g}_S)$ be the normal vector bundle, i.e.:
$$\mathscr{N}(\mathfrak{g}_S):=\text{End}(TM)/\mathfrak{g}_S$$
where $\mathfrak{g}_S$ is the bundle of infinitesimal automorphism of $S$.
More precisely the fibers of this vector bundle
$$\mathfrak{g}_{S,x}=\mathfrak{gl}(T_xM,S_x)\subset \text{End}(T_xM)$$
are the Lie algebras of the groups $\text{GL}(T_xM,S_x)$. Here with $\text{GL}(T_xM,S_x)$ is the group of automorphisms of the linear $G$-structures $S_x$.
I dont understand the proof of the following

For a $G$-structure $S$ on $M$ and a connection $\nabla$ on $TM$, one has an element $$\nabla(S)\in\Omega^1(M,\mathscr{N}(\mathfrak{g}_S))$$
such that $\nabla$ is compatible with $S$ if and only if $\nabla(S)=0$.

Crainic gives a construction of $\nabla(S)$ which is the following.
Let look at a curve $\gamma$ in $M$ starting at $x\in M$, and a curve $u$ in $S$ sitting above $\gamma$.
Then $u(t)\in S_{\gamma(t)}$ is a frame at $\gamma(t)$ and we can use the inverse of the parallel transport along $\gamma$,
$$T_\gamma^{t,0}=(T_\gamma^{0,t})^{-1}:T_{\gamma(t)}M\to T_xM.$$
The new frame at $x$ is
$$T_\gamma^{t,0}\circ u(t)\in \text{Fr}(T_xM).$$
The question is now if this frame still belongs to $S_x$.
This can be measured by comparing this frame with $u(0)$, i.e. by looking at
$$A_u(t)=T_\gamma^{t,0}\circ u(t)\circ u(0)^{-1}\in \text{GL}(T_xM);$$
the question is whether this path takes value in $\text{GL}(T_xM,S_x)$.
This path starts, at $t=0$, with the identity.
Crainic now says that the variation we are interested in is
$$\left[\frac{dA_u}{dt}(0)\right]\in\mathscr{N}(\mathfrak{g}_{S,x}).$$
Then he defines $\nabla(S)$ as:
$$\nabla_v(S):=\left[\frac{dA_u}{dt}(0)\right],$$
with $\gamma$ such that $\dot{\gamma}(0)=v$.
I don't understand why this definition doesnt depend on the choice of $u$ and why if this derivative is zero modulo $\mathfrak{g}_{S,x}$ the path $A_u(t)$ takes values in $\text{GL}(T_xM,S_x)$.

That $\nabla_v(S)$ does not depend on the choice of $u$ can be seen as follows:
Each other curve $\tilde u$ in $S$ sitting above $\gamma$ can be expressed as $\tilde u=ug$ for some $G$-valued function $g$. Then $A_{\tilde u}(t)=A_u(t)\circ\mu(t)$ with $\mu(t):=u(0)\circ g(t)g^{-1}(0)\circ u^{-1}(0)$ and hence by the product rule
$$
\frac{dA_{\tilde u}}{dt}(0)=\frac{dA_u}{dt}(0)\circ\mu(0)+A_u(0)\circ\frac{d\mu}{dt}(0)=\frac{dA_u}{dt}(0)+\frac{d\mu}{dt}(0)
$$
Now $\frac{d\mu}{dt}(0)\in\mathfrak{g}_{S,x}$ since $\mu$ takes values in $\text{GL}(T_xM,S_x)$ with $\mu(0)=e$ and hence $$[\frac{dA_{\tilde u}}{dt}(0)]=[\frac{dA_{ u}}{dt}(0)]$$
The next thing one can show is, that for an arbitrary $S$-compatible connection $\nabla^0$
$$
\nabla_v(S)=\left[\nabla_v-\nabla_v^0\right]
$$
The expression on the right hand side makes sense, since the difference of two affine connections is given by an endomorphism valued one-form. As a consequence, $\nabla_v(S)$ does also not depend on the choice of $\gamma$ and since the compatible connections form an affine space over $\Omega^1(M,{\mathfrak g}_S)$, the connection $\nabla$ is compatible with $S$ if and only if $\nabla(S)=0$.
To prove the claim, one can assume $v\neq 0$ and it is enough to find a specific $u$ for which
$$
\frac{dA_u}{dt}(0)=\nabla_v-\nabla_v^0
$$Let $ P^{t,s}:T_{\gamma(s)}M\to T_{\gamma(t)}M$ and $Q^{t,s}:T_{\gamma(s)}M\to T_{\gamma(t)}M$ be the parallel transport maps of $\nabla$ and $\nabla^0$. Fix $u_0\in S_x$ and set $u(t):=Q^{t,0}\circ u_0$ so that $A_u(t)=P^{0,t}\circ Q^{t,0}$.
Now let $\xi\in T_xM$ be arbitrary and choose a vector field $\psi\in\mathfrak X(M)$ such that $\psi_{\gamma(t)}=Q^{t,0}(\xi)$ for all $t$ in an open interval containing $0$. Then
$$
\frac{dA_u}{dt}(0)(\xi)
=\frac{dA_u(\xi)}{dt}(0)
=\frac{P^{0,t}\circ Q^{t,0}(\xi)}{dt}(0)
=\frac{P^{0,t}(\psi_{\gamma(t)})}{dt}(0)\\
=\frac{P^{0,t}(\psi_{\gamma(t)})}{dt}(0)-\frac{Q^{0,t}(\psi_{\gamma(t)})}{dt}(0)
=\nabla_v\psi-\nabla_v^0\psi
=(\nabla_v-\nabla_v^0)(\xi)
$$
where in the last line we have used the formula for recovering a connection from it's parallel transport maps.

Your proof that $\nabla$ doesn't depend on the choice of $\gamma$ assumes the existence of a $S$-compatible connection $\nabla^0$, right? What if such a connection doesn't exist?

@Kandinskij Yes, that's correct. But S-compatible connections always exist. They are in bijection with the principal connections on S (Proposition 4.3. in the linked lecture notes).
